# object is to class as enum is to ...?

Tags: c#, java, enums

### **object is to class as enum is to ...?**

I'm using C# but I'd like the answer for Java as well, if there is one.

Thank you, as always.

Comment: object is to class as *value* is to enum, not the other way around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether we're discussing C# or Java, the sentence cannot be completed the way you expect it to, because of the following fundamental flaw in it: both enum and class are *types*, whereas an object is a particular *instance* of a type.

In C#, an enum is a value type that restricts an underlying numeric type by defining acceptable values and (optionally) combinations of those values for the underlying type. Given the following example:

```
enum Days { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
```

we say that **Days** is an *enum*, while **Monday** is one of its *values*.

In Java, an enum is a *class* defined using special syntax that defines unique, distinguished, publicly accessible instances of it. An enum is final, i.e. it cannot be extended.

Answer (score 5):

"Enum is to Value Type"

Enums are strongly typed constants

In the C# tradition, they are strongly typed, meaning that an enum of one type may not be implicitly assigned to an enum of another type even though the underlying value of their members are the same.

Enums are value types, which means they contain their own value, can't inherit or be inherited from, and assignment copies the value of one enum to another.

Enums are used and referred to with both lower case, enum, and upper case, Enum. The relationship between the two is that the C# type, enum, inherits the Base Class Library (BCL) type, Enum. Use the C# type, enum, to define new enums and use the BCL type, Enum, to implement static enum methods.

Source: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson17.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In Java, Enum is now a type of class, so you can have an enum object.

Comment: That's the Java answer.  Is the same true for C#?

(Too bad you can't set more than one reply as answer)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about C#, but in most cases they seem pretty similar. VBNight has provided a reasonable answer though.

Comment: I believe C# enums are like ints rather than objects. The same is true in C and C++. I believe C++0x is due to have Java-like enums.

Comment: for java, i would think "object is to class as enum is to class-file". object is an instance of a class, and enum is an instance of the class file from which it was loaded. oO

Answer (score 2):

Object is to class as enum is to set.

Answer (score 0):

An Object is an instance of a class. enum is an example of a keyword.